# How to extract only last record in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there any chance to read only last record using pig script? I'm able to read first record using limit.

```
a = load "myFile.txt";
b = limit a 1;
```

this will give me first record.

Similarly is there any way to read only last record in pig?

Answer (score 1):

I apologise but have tried (on Linux or OS X):

```
 tail -1 myFile.txt
```

Why would you use Apache Pig for that? It wasn't created for this.

Comment: Agree your point. I'm using pig to count total records in the file and also to remove header trailer records in final output file. Trailer record which appears at the end of file will contain a number with total records like #Trailer 34938. Need to write this number in seperate file so that I can match the total actual count I received.